# Comando para combinação de inteiros. C++

Tags: c++

Existe algum comando que possibilite a combinação de dois inteiros?

Eu tenho uma variável que vale `5` e uma que vale `6` por exemplo, existe algum comando que possibilite jogar a combinação dessas variáveis, o valor `56`, em uma terceira variável?

Comment: me parece que ainda não tem problema conforme definido na [Central de Ajuda](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Procure [mostrar o que fez, definir melhor sua dúvida](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Sim, tem vários. Seja `a` a sua primeira variável, e `b` a segunda. Um exemplo de comando que faz o que você quer é: `c = a * 10 + b`. Mas como já comentado, o seu problema não tá assim tão bem definido. Como você pode ver, você recebeu várias respostas distintas, todas válidas *em algum contexto*. E perguntas assim não são muito bem vindas neste site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segue uma outra alternativa usando [`Stringstream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int num1, num2, num3;
    stringstream ss;

    num1 = 505;
    num2 = 560;

    ss << num1 << num2;
    ss >> num3;

    cout << num3 << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[Ver `demonstração`](http://ideone.com/I1F1sa)

Answer (score 3):

A resposta curta é:

```
unsigned concatenate(unsigned x, unsigned y) {
    unsigned pow = 10;
    while(y >= pow)
        pow *= 10;
   return x * pow + y;        
}
```

Todo o crédito para: [Resposta em Inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12700533/2285259)