# Conversão de variáveis tipo int para o tipo char*. C++

Tags: c, c++, conversão-de-tipo

Eu tenho o seguinte método que recebe duas variáveis int como parâmetro e preciso concatenar esses dois valores em uma variável char*, só que para que isso seja possível é necessário que essas duas variáveis int sejam convertidas para o tipo char*.

```
void exemplo(int amountVariables1, int amountVariables2){
   char *strPosition;
   //código para conversão de amountVariables1 e amountVariables2.
   strPosition = strcat(amountVariables1, amountVariables2);
}
```

Como devo realizar a conversão do tipo para que seja possível realizar a concatenação dessas variáveis?

Comment: Evandro, procure decidir se vai fazer em C ou C++ e usar a tag apropriada. (a versão em português do site ainda é nova e boazinha, então ninguém reclama muito)

Comment: Está me parecendo que este assunto é exatamente o mesmo [desta sua outra pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/143029/73) (apesar de agora você ter sido mais claro). Se for o caso, não abra múltiplas perguntas para uma mesma dúvida, ok? Ao invés, edite a pergunta original para deixá-la mais clara.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dá pra fazer com **sprintf**:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void exemplo(int i1, int i2) {
    char s[16];
    sprintf(s, "%d%d", i1, i2);
    printf(s);
}

void main() {
    exemplo(12, 34);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Que tal:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char * concatint( char * str, int a, int b )
{
    sprintf( str, "%d%d", a, b );
    return str;
}

int main ( void )
{
    char str[ 100 ] = {0};

    printf( "%s\n", concatint( str, 123, 456 ) );
    printf( "%s\n", concatint( str, 1, 2 ) );
    printf( "%s\n", concatint( str, 1000, 9999 ) );
    printf( "%s\n", concatint( str, 0, 0 ) );

    return 0;
}

/* fim-de-arquivo */
```

Saída:

```
$ ./concatint 
123456
12
10009999
00
```

Answer (score 1):

Segue uma outra forma (C++11):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

string concatInt(int num1, int num2){
    stringstream ss;
    ss << num1 << num2;

    return ss.str();
}

int main() {
    string strPosition = concatInt(1, 11);
    // Converte String para char*
    char* chrPosition = &strPosition[0]; 

    cout << chrPosition << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

[Ver `demonstração`](http://ideone.com/KBgLoL)